# Sentiment Analysis using LSTM (Model has not not generate good output)

Tags: nlp, nltk, lstm

I Make a sentiment analysis model using LSTM but my model gives very bad prediction.

[Here is the complete code](https://github.com/BUBAIMITRA2018/AI-ml/blob/master/lstm_sentimentanalysis_model.ipynb)

[Dataset for amazon review](https://www.kaggle.com/subrata2019/amazonreview)

My LSTM model looks like this:

```
def ltsm_model(input_shape, word_to_vec_map, word_to_index):
"""
Function creating the ltsm_model model's graph.

Arguments:
input_shape -- shape of the input, usually (max_len,)
word_to_vec_map -- dictionary mapping every word in a vocabulary into its 50-dimensional vector representation
word_to_index -- dictionary mapping from words to their indices in the vocabulary (400,001 words)

Returns:
model -- a model instance in Keras
"""

### START CODE HERE ###
# Define sentence_indices as the input of the graph, it should be of shape input_shape and dtype 'int32' (as it contains indices).
sentence_indices =  Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='int32')

# Create the embedding layer pretrained with GloVe Vectors (≈1 line)
embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index)

# Propagate sentence_indices through your embedding layer, you get back the embeddings
embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)   

# Propagate the embeddings through an LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
# Be careful, the returned output should be a batch of sequences.
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(embeddings)
# Add dropout with a probability of 0.5
X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
# Propagate X trough another LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
# Be careful, the returned output should be a single hidden state, not a batch of sequences.
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False)(X)
# Add dropout with a probability of 0.5
X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
# Propagate X through a Dense layer with softmax activation to get back a batch of 5-dimensional vectors.
X = Dense(2, activation='relu')(X)
# Add a softmax activation
X = Activation('softmax')(X)

# Create Model instance which converts sentence_indices into X.
model = Model(inputs=[sentence_indices], outputs=X)

### END CODE HERE ###

return model
```

Here is what my training dataset looks like:

[image]

This is my testing data:

```
x_test = np.array(['amazing!: this soundtrack is my favorite music..'])
X_test_indices = sentences_to_indices(x_test, word_to_index, maxLen)
print(x_test[0] +' '+  str(np.argmax(model.predict(X_test_indices))))
```

I got following out for this:

> amazing!: this soundtrack is my favorite music.. 0

But it should be positive sentiment and should be 1

Also this my fit model output:

[image: Fit model output]

How can I improve my model performance? This pretty bad model I suppose.

Comment: Any help regarding this?